# Python running matplotlib.nxutils points_inside_poly on mac

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, osx-lion

Everything works fine with my code on my ubuntu box but when I run the same code on my mac, I get ValueError.  I am running python 2.7.3

```
inside = points_inside_poly(coord, x[:,0:2])
ValueError: Argument verts must be a Nx2 array.
```

Any idea?

Comment: Please post self contained code that reproduces the problem. The error message is very clear and points at a problem with the shape of your input arrays.

Answer (score 3):

The nxutils module [was deprecated in version 1.2.0](http://matplotlib.org/api/nxutils_api.html). 
You can do a containment test with something like:

```
>>> from matplotlib.path import Path
>>> Path([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 0], [0, 0]]).contains_point([0.5, 0.5])
1
>>> Path([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 0], [0, 0]]).contains_point([0.5, 2.5])
0
```

HTH